# Visualizing a large number of variables in python

Tags: python, visualization

I have a large number of variables (2000) and want to visualize them using Python. Also, I would like to see the summary statistics of these variables. It seems that drawing box plots for all of these variables would not be feasible. What are some methods that could be used to visualize this data?

Comment: I wonder if you might be after some dimensionality reduction techniques like principal components analysis?

Answer (score 1):

You can load these variables to pandas dataframe and use [`dataframe.describe()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) for summary statistics.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, then you can use any of the below libraries. These are simple to use and you can customize them as per your requirement.

The libraries are--

- [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html)
- [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html)
- [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/)
- [ggplot](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/)
- [pygal](http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/index.html)
- [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/)
- [geoplotlib](https://github.com/andrea-cuttone/geoplotlib)
- [Gleam](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gleam)
- [missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno)
- [Leather](http://leather.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

You can use any but as per your data I would recommend you to go with `Plotly , Seaborn or Bokeh`. For chart-codes and description you can try- [One Chart, Twelve Charting Libraries](http://lisacharlotterost.github.io/2016/05/17/one-chart-code/)

If you need any other help on this update me. I would help to help. Cheers! :)

Comment: This is a very generic list of libraries for plotting. It does not answer the question of OP in regards to which would be better for the specific problem at hand.

Comment: Have a look, there is an ending paragraph, which clearly states that. Cheers!